# Line artifact on my OpenGL Textures/Geometry

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I really hope you guys can help, I don't like to ask many questions if I can but this one is really hurting my brain. Thanks in advance.

I've recently dove into modern OpenGL(3.3) and I've been trying to build a simple 2D game. It's all in 3D but I use triangles for single quads (for sprites).

Everything was working fine but when I decided to implement alpha channels I get a line going from every vertex-- basically a ~1px wireframe cage on all my geometry.

Here is the scene: (this is a very zoomed in scene)

[image]

Verts:

```
m_New_Vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-1.0, -1.0, m_Location.z));
m_New_Vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(1.0, -1.0, m_Location.z));
m_New_Vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-1.0, 1.0, m_Location.z)); 
m_New_Vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-1.0, 1.0, m_Location.z));
m_New_Vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(1.0, -1.0, m_Location.z)); 
m_New_Vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(1.0, 1.0, m_Location.z));
```

Texture Loading:

```
m_Texture = LoadTexture("FILE.png", NULL, NULL); //see below for function defenition
```

Rendering: (I left out data for initializing/binding other buffers for simplicity)

```
glUseProgram(SHADERPROGRAM_IM_USING);

//Bind buffers here

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture);
glUniform1i(m_TextureID, 0); //TextureID is Initiated in my Init function

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_New_Vertices.size());

//Unbind buffers here
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core
// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec2 UV;
in vec3 Position_worldspace;
in vec3 Normal_cameraspace;
in vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace;
in vec3 LightDirection_cameraspace;

// Ouput data
out vec4 color;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform sampler2D myTextureSampler;
uniform mat4 MV;
uniform vec3 LightPosition_worldspace;

void main(){

vec3 LightColor = vec3(1, 1, 1);
float LightPower = 50.0;

vec4 MaterialDiffuseColor;
MaterialDiffuseColor.rgb = texture2D(myTextureSampler, UV).rgb;
MaterialDiffuseColor.a = texture2D(myTextureSampler, UV).a;
vec3 MaterialAmbientColor = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3) * MaterialDiffuseColor.rgb;
vec3 MaterialSpecularColor = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);

float distance = length(LightPosition_worldspace - Position_worldspace);

vec3 n = normalize(Normal_cameraspace);
vec3 l = normalize(LightDirection_cameraspace);

float cosTheta = clamp(dot(n, l), 0, 1);

vec3 E = normalize(EyeDirection_cameraspace);
vec3 R = reflect(-l, n);

float cosAlpha = clamp(dot(E, R), 0, 1);

color.rgb = MaterialAmbientColor + (MaterialDiffuseColor.rgb) * LightColor * LightPower * cosTheta / (distance*distance)
+ MaterialSpecularColor * LightColor * LightPower * pow(cosAlpha, 5) / (distance*distance);
color.a = MaterialDiffuseColor.a;

// Output color = color of the texture at the specified UV
//color = texture2D( myTextureSampler, UV ).rgb;
}
```

LoadTexture:

```
GLuint LoadTexture(const char * file_name, int *width, int *height)
{
    png_byte header[8];

    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        perror(file_name);
        return 0;
    }

    // read the header
    fread(header, 1, 8, fp);

    if (png_sig_cmp(header, 0, 8))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s is not a PNG.\n", file_name);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    png_structp png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (!png_ptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: png_create_read_struct returned 0.\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    // create png info struct
    png_infop info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
    if (!info_ptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: png_create_info_struct returned 0.\n");
        png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, (png_infopp)NULL, (png_infopp)NULL);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    // create png info struct
    png_infop end_info = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
    if (!end_info)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: png_create_info_struct returned 0.\n");
        png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, (png_infopp)NULL);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    // the code in this if statement gets called if libpng encounters an error
    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error from libpng\n");
        png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, &end_info);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    // init png reading
    png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);

    // let libpng know you already read the first 8 bytes
    png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, 8);

    // read all the info up to the image data
    png_read_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

    // variables to pass to get info
    int bit_depth, color_type;
    png_uint_32 temp_width, temp_height;

    // get info about png
    png_get_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, &temp_width, &temp_height, &bit_depth, &color_type,
        NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (width){ *width = temp_width; }
    if (height){ *height = temp_height; }

    //printf("%s: %lux%lu %d\n", file_name, temp_width, temp_height, color_type);

    if (bit_depth != 8)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Unsupported bit depth %d.  Must be 8.\n", file_name, bit_depth);
        return 0;
    }

    GLint format;
    switch (color_type)
    {
    case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB:
        format = GL_RGB;
        break;
    case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB_ALPHA:
        format = GL_RGBA;
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Unknown libpng color type %d.\n", file_name, color_type);
        return 0;
    }

    // Update the png info struct.
    png_read_update_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

    // Row size in bytes.
    int rowbytes = png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr, info_ptr);

    // glTexImage2d requires rows to be 4-byte aligned
    rowbytes += 3 - ((rowbytes - 1) % 4);

    // Allocate the image_data as a big block, to be given to opengl
    png_byte * image_data = (png_byte *)malloc(rowbytes * temp_height * sizeof(png_byte) + 15);
    if (image_data == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: could not allocate memory for PNG image data\n");
        png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, &end_info);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    // row_pointers is for pointing to image_data for reading the png with libpng
    png_byte ** row_pointers = (png_byte **)malloc(temp_height * sizeof(png_byte *));
    if (row_pointers == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: could not allocate memory for PNG row pointers\n");
        png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, &end_info);
        free(image_data);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    // set the individual row_pointers to point at the correct offsets of image_data
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < temp_height; i++)
    {
        row_pointers[temp_height - 1 - i] = image_data + i * rowbytes;
    }

    // read the png into image_data through row_pointers
    png_read_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);

    // Generate the OpenGL texture object
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, temp_width, temp_height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    // clean up
    png_destroy_read_struct(&png_ptr, &info_ptr, &end_info);
    free(image_data);
    free(row_pointers);
    fclose(fp);
    return texture;
}
```

Comment: Do you have Polygon smoothing enabled in OpenGL? If you do try disabling it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know such a small piece of code could solve such a huge headace. I actually thought it was the anti-aliasing at first. I changed my nvidia settings for it but got no result. I also noticed that if I changed the monitor(say I plug in an output HMDI to a TV screen) the artifact would disappear.

Comment: OpenGL is a fickle beast, lacking any of the testing rigor libraries like Direct3D get can lead to interesting visual bugs for apparently no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by using

```
glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
```

Thank MorphingDragon for the answer, I'm just posting as an answer for other people.

Although MorphingDragon did not give me the direct answer, he pointed me in the right direction, so I believe he deserves credit.

Comment: You may also try ` GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` for wrapping.